# Delphi 10 Seattle trial fails to compile anything, gives an MSBuild error

Tags: delphi, msbuild, delphi-10-seattle

I downloaded and installed the Delphi 10 trial. However, every time I try to build anything at all, I get this: **MSBuildToolsPath is not specified for the ToolsVersion "12.0" defined at "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\12.0", or the value specified evaluated to the empty string**

The 12.0 key does **not** exist within "ToolsVersions" on my pc. I **do** however have 2.0, 3.5, 4.0 and 14.0. I also have a full, perfectly-working installation of Visual Studio 2015 Community, if that knowledge helps. I am running Windows 10 Pro, 64-Bit. What can I do to correct this issue? It's the first time I've ever had a problem with any version of Delphi/RAD Studio... was actually not aware the Rad Studio IDE cared about or used or had anything to do with MSBuild until now.

Comment: Are you trying to build out of process?

Comment: No. It originally happened immediately after I had first started the IDE, when I was simply trying to install SynEdit through the GetIt package manager, not even building an actual project.... And the real projects I have tried to build since then all have the out-of-process option turned off.

Comment: This is an installation related issue. You should open a free support case at [Embarcadero Support](http://support.embarcadero.com).

Comment: MSBuild 12.0 can be found from Microsoft download. It is also part of Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 2):

I resolve my problem in delphi that need the Msbuild 14, i just download and install the msbuild that match my error message, in my case:
 https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48159

i think that you could download the msbuild from microsoft site to see if it works.

Answer (score 2):

It is a known issue, documented here:
https://community.embarcadero.com/article/technical-articles/16202-msbuildtoolspath-is-not-specified-for-the-toolsversion

> This error is caused by incorrect values in the registry. On a 32 OS, run regedit and navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild. On a 64 bit OS, run regedit and navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSBuild. First, backup this registry key by selecting File | Export. Next, look at the numbers below the ToolsVersions key. Delete any number not found at the MSBuild level.
>   ...
>   There is anecdotal evidence to suggest this registry key imbalance is caused by uninstalling some versions of Visual Studio, but it has not been confirmed at this time.

Since I've been installing/uninstalling various Visual Studio versions (including previews), guess it has indeed been caused by that

Error "A default tools version "2.0" was specified, but its definition could not be found." may appear then if you deleted the 2.0 key following the 1st article's advice. Solution for that one is to edit each value under MSBuild key in the registry locations mentioned for x32 and x64 and change DefaultToolsVersion to 14.0 or other highest MSBuild tools version that is installed

Note that on x64 machine you need to fix these two issues for both x32 and x64 registry locations, since the IDE is 32-bit process and if you fix x64 location only it will fail internally, underlining all Standard units at uses clause in your source code and showing “Cannot resolve unit name xx”

Also it may be useful to install this:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48159

This may also be useful to know (copying from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383985.aspx):

> Order of Precedence
>
> The order of precedence, from highest to lowest, used to determine the ToolsVersion is:
>   The ToolsVersion attribute on the MSBuild task used to build the project, if any.
>
> The /toolsversion (or /tv) switch that's used in the msbuild.exe command, if any.
>
> If the environment variable MSBUILDTREATALLTOOLSVERSIONSASCURRENT is set, then use the current ToolsVersion.
>
> If the environment variable MSBUILDTREATHIGHERTOOLSVERSIONASCURRENT is set and the ToolsVersion defined in the project file is greater than the current ToolsVersion, use the current ToolsVersion.
>
> If the environment variable MSBUILDLEGACYDEFAULTTOOLSVERSION is set, or if ToolsVersion is not set, then the following steps are used:
>
> The ToolsVersion attribute of the Project element of the project file. If this attribute doesn’t exist, it is assumed to be the current version.
>
> The default tools version in the MSBuild.exe.config file.
>
> The default tools version in the registry. For more information, see Standard and Custom Toolset Configurations.
>
> If the environment variable MSBUILDLEGACYDEFAULTTOOLSVERSION is not set, then the following steps are used:
>
> If the environment variable MSBUILDDEFAULTTOOLSVERSION is set to a ToolsVersion that exists, use it.
>
> If DefaultOverrideToolsVersion is set in MSBuild.exe.config, use it.
>
> If DefaultOverrideToolsVersion is set in the registry, use it.
>
> Otherwise, use the current ToolsVersion.

Comment: Added related screenshots at a blog post https://zoomicon.wordpress.com/2017/03/06/fix-delphi-error-msbuildtoolspath-is-not-specified-for-the-toolsversion/

Answer (score 0):

Great, [Sandro Adad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074145/sandro-adad) your advice immediately helped and fixed opening projects in Delphi 10.4 :-) After installing Microsoft Build Tools 2015, an entry reported by Delphi in the registry 14.0 was added.

[image]